# GKE Node Pool Showing Error after Google networking crash on 29 Jun 2020

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-networking/20005

After this issue gke node pool (master in: us-east1-c) is throwing error, which is crashing the terraform plan.
[image]

I tried to get status using `gcloud container clusters describe` and the node pool gave this error:

[image]
[image]

Can anyone explain what is this error `INTERNAL_ERROR: internal error: updateinfo initial cleanup failed` and how to solve this.

Comment: Are you able to list node pools in this cluster by `gcloud container node-pools list --zone <zone> --cluster <cluster-name>` and then `gcloud container node-pools describe primary-pool` ? Could you also try to refetch credentials `gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone <zone-name> cluster-name`, just in case ? You may also try to run `gcloud container operations list --zone <zone-name>` and check if there is some relevant info there.

Comment: In worst case scenario you may always create a new nodepool and delete this one. And what about any details of the error massege you can see in GCP console next to your node pool name ? Is it similar to the console output from the attached screenshot ?

Comment: Are there any more details when you click on this node pool name ? What about the status of particular nodes ?

Comment: Yes @mario I can list the node pools and describe it also but the same error is coming if I describe it. But all nodes are up and running and all services are fine. But when I try to get the status of node pool it is failing and showing this error.

Comment: The exact error I am getting is this:
`statusMessage: 'INTERNAL_ERROR: internal error: updateinfo initial cleanup failed
  - listing updateinfos failed: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (5 attempts):
  Get "https://35.196.84.1/apis/nodemanagement.gke.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/kube-system/updateinfos":
  harpoon unreachable error UNREACHABLE_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`

Comment: Did you try to refetch credentials ? Are you able at the same time to perform any operations using `kubectl` like `kubectl get nodes` on this cluster ?

Comment: yes all kubectl  commands are working, like get node or describe pod.

Comment: it looks like a problem with **master node**. I would recommend you to create a new issue on [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks for the info, we've already deleted the old node pool and created a new one, now its working correctly.